# How to stop code from running when error is found?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm just doing a small application and i have a clause in here that says

```
If hoursPerPeriod > 0 And salary > 0 Then
        If numberPayPeriods = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter number of pay periods!")
        End If
        txtCalculatedPaycheckGross.Text = salary / numberPayPeriods
    End If
```

So if the user is entering in their paycheck info and fill out their hourly and salary, the program will only calulate their salary. but if the number of pay periods box is 0, it wont calculate anything until that is fixed. The problem is, how do I stop the code from continuing after i display the messagebox asking them to enter in a value?

Comment: use a `else` statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
If hoursPerPeriod > 0 And salary > 0 Then
        If numberPayPeriods = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter number of pay periods!")
        else
            txtCalculatedPaycheckGross.Text = salary / numberPayPeriods
        end if
    End If
```